# Java 17 String Deduplication

Tags: java, memory

My app Java version was upgraded to Java 17 from Java 8. While testing memory usage of the new version I’ve noticed a huge decrease (more than 50%) in the memory usage. I used parallel gc so string deduplication feature is supposed to be off and there were no major changes to the code other than strictly needed changes for the upgrade. Is there an explanation for this decrease?

Comment: It could partially be due to compact Strings that were added in Java 9. If all characters of the String can be represented using a Latin-1 encoding, then the String will use a `byte[]` internally rather than a `char[]`, which saves memory.

Comment: @JacobG. I thought it might be the reason, however there is also a similar decrease in the number of strings

Comment: Can you make a heapdump in both versions and check for differences? Among others, you might want to look into both the amount of objects and required memory by them of specific classes but also at the fractions of memory which is reachable vs unreachable (could be GCed). You can use a tool like [Eclipse MAT](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.mat) for analyzing that.